# How to Programmatically Enable/Disable Accessibility Service in Android

Tags: android, service, accessibility

I would like to programmatically enable/disable Accessibility Services listed under Settings->Accessibility option.

I could start Accessibility Intent like below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

But I don't have any idea on how to enable the services listed in the view through my code.

Please, provide me your views.

Answer (score 29):

I found a solution worked for me by calling

```
Settings.Secure.putString(getContentResolver(), 
    Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES, "pkgname/classname");
Settings.Secure.putString(getContentResolver(), 
    Settings.Secure.ACCESSIBILITY_ENABLED, "1");
```

Where the `pkgname` is your package name and the `classname` is the class name of your accessibility service.

If you need to enable several services or you don't want to destory the previous settings you might want to use `:` to seperate other services.

Also you might need to run as a **system application** and you might need the following permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
```

However, according to [@Rupert Rawnsley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061154/how-to-programmatically-enable-disable-accessibility-service-in-android?newreg=d7f99d8d33064ff1961b298051e2c62b#comment37905847_10740671) this might not work on some versions of Android, I am working on Android 4.0.4 and hope it works for you.

PS. If it doesn't work, maybe you could find some luck in `/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db/secure`, that's where Android stores secure settings.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" /> is given to only system applications so this solution will not work for non-system applications

Comment: @Kushal Yes, this solution works only for system applications (or non-sys apps if your phone is rooted). And I think a non-system app might not be able to programmically enable an Accessibility Service due to security issues.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question. Whats the packagename and whats the classname? com.somepackage/MyAcessibilityService is this the right way?

Comment: @Alex Sorry it's been quite a long time and I don't have the code now. But as far as I remember, it should be com.somepackage/.MyAcessibilityService or com.somepackage/com.sompackage.MyAcessibilityService.

Also, I found that a newer version of Android might simply ignore this code. I had to write the database directly. Might be a little bit ugly, but it worked. FYI

Comment: How did you guys succeed using this? It shows me an exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denial: writing to settings requires:android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS

Comment: @androiddeveloper android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS is given to System apps only!

Comment: Well I don't see the folder "/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/" at all either, even though I have a rooted device.

Answer (score 17):

From Android 6.0 you can use:

```
adb shell settings put secure enabled_accessibility_services packagname/servicename
```

The settings.db from old releases is no longer present on Android 6.0.

Comment: Does it work even on android 7? Also, how do I enable usage access via adb?

Comment: OP is about how to programmatically enable/disable the accessibility service not using adb shell

Comment: If you can run it in console, then you can run it programmatically in test:
`InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation(UiAutomation.FLAG_DONT_SUPPRESS_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES).executeShellCommand("...")`

Comment: I came across this while trying to figure out how to enable via adb for DarQ... Here is the command that worked: `adb shell settings put secure enabled_accessibility_services com.kieronquinn.app.darq/.services.DarqBackgroundService`

Answer (score 15):

In Android 7 (API 24), an AccessibilityService can programmatically disable itself by calling the [disableSelf()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html#disableSelf()) method.

Comment: But how to get the instance of the service? I don't think I could simply call the primary constructor :/

Comment: use a static reference like this: `static WeakReference<MyAccessibilityService> ref = null` and then in your service's `onCreate()` use `if(ref != null && ref.get() != null) ref.get().disableSelf();`. Use the WeakReference to avoid memory leaks

Answer (score 6):

AccessibilityService is special and cannot be started programmatically.

Comment: From [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081145/android-how-do-you-check-if-a-particular-accessibilityservice-is-enabled/5106419#5106419), the enabled AccessibilityService is stored as a String from `Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES)`. Isn't it possible to enable AccessibilityService by following the String format and call `Settings.Secure.putString(...)` once the app has system privilege?

Comment: @Yeung In principle, but in practice I've found this to be hit-and-miss depending on the version of Android and the device. The process that controls Accessibility Services doesn't always see those changes without a reboot. In our app we direct the user to the settings page and have them enable the service for us.

Comment: @Yeung Settings.Secure.putString(...) works only for system applications. For other applications, Android do not allow to turn accessibility service programmatically

Comment: @Kushal you can grant this permission from adb ( adb shell pm grant yourpackagename android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS)

Answer (score 5):

The best you can do is manualy open the accessibilty settings with:

> Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS)

and start the intent - you can also do it from the prefernece xml file:

> intent android:action="android.settings.ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS"

Comment: Is it possible to go directly to the specific app's screen that has the toggle there ?

Answer (score 4):

In instrumented tests I start my accessibility service like this:

```
private fun enableAccessibilityService() {
    val packageName = "com.example"
    val className = "$packageName.service.MyService"
    val string = "enabled_accessibility_services"
    val cmd = "settings put secure $string $packageName/$className"
    InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()
      .getUiAutomation(UiAutomation.FLAG_DONT_SUPPRESS_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES)
      .executeShellCommand(cmd)
      .close()
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3)
}
```

I tested on Android 6 and 8. This also works for non-system apps.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anybody still seeks to **turn off** talkback from adb when you are stuck in your lock screen entering the password or pin. One thing you can try is `adb shell am force-stop com.google.android.marvin.talkback`

Answer (score 3):

Here is the working solution (if your activity is not running it will disable itself)

```
@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    super.onServiceConnected();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Connected!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            serviceChecker();
        }
    }, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

private void serviceChecker(){
    if(!isActivityRunning(MainActivity.class)) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            disableSelf();
        }
    }
}
protected Boolean isActivityRunning(Class activityClass)
{
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> tasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    for (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo task : tasks) {
        if (activityClass.getCanonicalName().equalsIgnoreCase(task.baseActivity.getClassName()))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can enable accessibility services for multiple apps by separating them by a colon, like this:

```
adb shell settings put secure enabled_accessibility_services com.app1/com.app1.MyAccessibilityService:com.app2/com.app2.MyAccessibilityService
```

Answer (score 0):

enabled_accessibility_services contains all the enabled services separated by ':'. It's something like 'serviceA:serviceB:serviceC'

If you replace the string, it will enable your service, but you will also disable everyone else's.

**The correct code would be:**

```
    fun enableAccessibility(activity: Activity) {
        var accessibilityServices: String? = Settings.Secure.getString(
            activity.contentResolver,
            Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES
        )

        if (accessibilityServices == null) {
            accessibilityServices = ""
        } else if (accessibilityServices.isNotEmpty()) {
            accessibilityServices = ":$accessibilityServices"
        }
        Settings.Secure.putString(
            activity.contentResolver,
            Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES,
            "${activity.applicationInfo.packageName}/${ForegroundDetectorService::class.java.canonicalName}$accessibilityServices"
        )
        Settings.Secure.putString(
            activity.contentResolver,
            Settings.Secure.ACCESSIBILITY_ENABLED, "1"
        )
    }
```

You only need to declare this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>
```

You can only enable this permission if you are rooted or via adb.

Answer (score -7):

I found this post: [How to programmatically check if a service is declared in AndroidManifest.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529069/how-to-programmatically-check-if-a-service-is-declared-in-androidmanifest-xml). The top answer talks about PackageManager, which tells you what is running.