# How to disable accessibility Service in android programatically

Tags: android, talkback

I am developing an app for visually impaired and I am creating my own sounds hence it doesn't need any help from the android accessibility service. So as soon as the app is opened I would like to disable the inbuilt accessibly service (if enabled) and out exit or going to different app I would like to enable it again?

Is this possible? if so how?

Comment: Please check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061154/how-to-programmatically-enable-disable-accessibility-service-in-android

Comment: Hi,TheAndroDev have u got answer i am also looking same