# How can I start the Accessibility Settings Page of my APP in Android?

Tags: android, settings, accessibility

I am developing an `Android` APP based on `Accessibility` feature. As it can't programmatically `Enable/Disable Accessibility` Service in Android(See [How to Programmatically Enable/Disable Accessibility Service in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061154/how-to-programmatically-enable-disable-accessibility-service-in-android)) , So I guide the user to `Accessibility Settings` Page(Pic 1) via the code below:

```
public static boolean gotoAccessibilitySettings(Context context) {
    Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(
            Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
    if (!(context instanceof Activity)) {
        settingsIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    }
    boolean isOk = true;
    try {
        context.startActivity(settingsIntent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        isOk = false;
    }
    return isOk;
}
```

And then the user need to find out the Sub Settings Label of my APP, click it, and now the `Accessibility Settings` Page of my APP show(Pic 2).

I doubt that if any way start my APP's `Accessibility Settings` Page(Pic 2) directly?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I&#39;m going crazy for do that

Comment: @kalok Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: hello guys, Any body find this solution? I also have same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the code below can help you :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClassName("com.android.settings",
                "com.android.settings.Settings");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
        intent.putExtra(PreferenceActivity.EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT,
                "the fragment which you want show");
        intent.putExtra(PreferenceActivity.EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT_ARGUMENTS,
                extras);
       startActivity(intent);
```

Or you can search the Key Word "Fragment Injection" for more information;
Check out this link,it is useful for you case:

- http://securityintelligence.com/new-vulnerability-android-framework-fragment-injection

Comment: @money zhang
what should i type in the "the fragment which you want show"?
i want to enter my own accessibility service settings..

Comment: I tried my app name, package name service class name and etc instead of "the fragment which you want show". please tell what should I type?

Comment: According to that link, this method no longer works as the vulnerability has been patched in Android 4.4 Kitkat

Answer (score 26):

You can manually open the accessibility settings with the following Intent (when `android.content.Intent` and `android.app.Intent` have both been imported):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

Check out the following resources for more information:

- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/accessibility/ClockBackActivity.java
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, ＠timgws. But my problem is open the accessibility settings of my own app directly, not the home page of accessibility settings :(

Comment: Ended up doing this. Until I figure out a better way to get to the page, I just tell the user to click on my app and enable the service from settings.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```