# How to open Accessibility Settings of my app programmatically?

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, accessibility, accessibility-api

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31802650/how-to-open-accessibility-settings-of-my-app-directly) I can open Android Accessibility Settings page; I know I can open my app Accessibility Settings directly with this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

But how can I start the Accessibility Settings Page of **my own APP** in Android? I want to guide user directly to my application **Accessibility** settings page to grant permissions.

I don't want to use adb and I can't root my device. I couldn't find any working solution; Any suggestions?

Comment: Hey ET1992. I'm facing the same issue, have you found a solution?

Comment: @Royz: Unfortunately no :(