# Android app: Take user to Accessibility settings page of my app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-settings

This question is quite similar to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29367093/how-can-i-start-the-accessibility-settings-page-of-my-app-in-android).

What I am currently using is the below code to take the user to setting page.

```
Intent dummyIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
startActivity(dummyIntent, 0);
```

But this takes the user only to the settings page. Shown below in the pic.
[image]

Instead of this, I would like to take the user to the settings page of my app, where he has the option to turn it on and shows my app description.

[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution for it?

Comment: No, it seems like android doesn't allow it

Comment: Android does allows it. I have seen many applications do this. I will find out and post the answer

Comment: @Vishaljotshi it's been almost 6 years, did you find out?

Answer (score -1):

> Refer This [DevicePolicyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager)

Eg:

if you want start change password

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_SET_NEW_PASSWORD);
startActivity(intent);
```