# How to add the app to auto start in order to receive firebase pushnotifications

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-package-managers

For receiving push notification from firebase, some phones require the user to add the app to autostart. This can be prompted to the user but there are apps on the play store that take the user directly to the auto start setting. Is there a universal code I can use that calls a certain intent or open a certain package. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Does [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391902/) help? Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29367093/)?

Comment: Give more details or sample code for your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @AjitZero i do not have any sample code yet because i do not know where to begin with this. The developer docs don't really mention anything other than a settings intent.

Comment: @AjitZero its not those links, since they are boot complete callbacks, i need the app to open a settings page for the user no matter which device they are on, which will allow them to put the app in their autostart list

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a universal code since this is more of an OEM specific issue and not an android issue. Having said that I have compiled a solution for a given set of OEM's at the [AutoStarter](https://github.com/judemanutd/AutoStarter) library, it will automatically open up the autostart permission manager of the phone.