# How to startActivity to accessibility settings page of my app in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, accessibility

This question is quite similar to [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29367093/how-can-i-start-the-accessibility-settings-page-of-my-app-in-android).
 
However there is still no solution.
I am using the below code to jump to the accessibility settings page.

```
       Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
       startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_USAGE_SETTING);
```

Instead of jump to main accessibility settings page, i would like to take the user to the settings page of my app.

Answer (score 0):

for open setting page of your app you need to pass package name of your application as below,
 try this it will redirect you to setting page of your application

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                        intent.setData(uri);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Comment: I have tried the code, however it shows an error: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS dat=packagename:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx }

Comment: i tested it work perfactily show your code how you implement it @林振弘

Comment: Thanks! It work perfectly!! However I want to jump to accessibility settings page of my app instead of the detail settings page.

Comment: My problem is jump to accessibility settings page of my app. However the code you provide do work perfectly to take user to detail setting page but not the  accessibility settings page.