# Opening Accessibility Android Settings

Tags: java, android

What i want to achieve here that user enable accessibility for my app i tried to program it but it's seems not quite easy i did also some research but nothing helpful.

[How to Programmatically Enable/Disable Accessibility Service in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061154/how-to-programmatically-enable-disable-accessibility-service-in-android)

[How can I start the Accessibility Settings Page of my APP in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29367093/how-can-i-start-the-accessibility-settings-page-of-my-app-in-android)

I can open accessibility menu from here

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

but how can i send user to this path as intent **Additional settings/Accessibility/MYAPPNAME**

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure to give you a specific answer, but this page can help you
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings

Comment: thanks but didn't help