# Accessibility Service is turned off automatically on each Run since Android studio 3.5

Tags: android, android-studio, accessibilityservice

Since I update Android Studio to 3.5, when I launch a Run to build and deploy my app, my custom accessibility service is turn off automatically (not a crash, just turn off within the settings).

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Is this also the case when an app update is installed from the Play Store?

Answer (score 4):

What's happening is that Studio force-stops the service before reinstalling the new version. I don't think it's possible to disable that unfortunately.

Command-line installation doesn't follow the same process, so it doesn't disable the service.

Comment: But that wasn't true for previous Android Studio versions. Maybe that's because of Instant Run/App Deploy changes in the latest release that broke something.

Comment: Yes I agree with you @Bringoff I open an issue at google if you want add a comment or just vote for this issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140056246

Answer (score 1):

In my case, *Android Studio was disabling the service* every time I hit the run button.

When I tried opening the app *manually*, **it worked!**

Comment: You can open an issue on google tracker or add a comment within this one https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140056246 . This issue is pretty old but not closed yet.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is pretty old but not closed yet. You can upvote and comment here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140056246