# Enable accessibility service by default in AOSP

Tags: java, android, android-source

- I'm using AOSP 13 code, and want to turn on accessibility service by default for custom apk.
- I am not able to do it from custom apk,as I only have apk file
- Is there any way I can do it from settings app or any other package from AOSP?

I am able to enable it via adb shell

```
adb shell settings put secure enabled_accessibility_services "com.example.yourapp/.YourAccessibilityService"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way is to write a small system service, and once the bootup is complete, you can programatically start the accessibility service. Please check this answer as well.

[How to Programmatically Enable/Disable Accessibility Service in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061154/how-to-programmatically-enable-disable-accessibility-service-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do by adding following code in

frameworks/base/services/accessibility/java/com/android/server/accessibility/AccessibilityManagerService.java

function name : switchUser()

```
// Get the ContentResolver
ContentResolver contentResolver = mContext.getContentResolver();

// Your Accessibility service
String myAccessibilityService = "<package name>/<accessibility service name>";

// Grant permission to your service
Settings.Secure.putInt(contentResolver, Settings.Secure.ACCESSIBILITY_ENABLED, 1 /* on */);
Settings.Secure.putString(contentResolver, Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES, myAccessibilityService);
```